# Path not found when running webui-user.bat

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

I am trying to install Stable diffusion for my machine but everytime I run "*webui-user.bat*" it tells me

```
venv "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Path not found
```

and when I check the *"venv"* file, the "*Scripts*" folder doesn't exist?

I guess the problem is when above those lines it says:

```
Creating venv in directory C:\Users\JimiJ\Desktop\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv using python "C:\Program Files\msys2\mingw64\bin\python.exe"
```

and for some reason I guess it doesn't create the venv correctly?

What could be the problem? I couldn't find anything online. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had *bin* folder instead of *Scripts* so I renamed the *bin* to *Scripts*.